# Mongodb query for arrays of combination two fields

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a document in the database:

```
{"name": "Jason", "score": 20, "color": "blue"}
```

And I have an array of data that contains documents with name and score, is there a way for me to query for the combination of the name and score via `$in`?  For example, if I had a list that looked like

```
var data = [
    {"name": "Bob", "score": 12}
    {"name": "Jason", "score": 20}
    {"name": "Tammy", "score": 19}
];
```

And I wanted to query the collection to see if any combination of `name` and `score` found within `data` existed within said collection, how could I do that?

Comment: The field itself is not an array, I want to query that field using an in-memory array. From the documentation: "The $elemMatch operator matches documents in a collection that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria."

Comment: For the record, the above response was me responding to a user who suggested I use the `$elemMatch` query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close because [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is actually a shortened form of [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). You already have the array there so:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$or": data })
```